# Random nat stream and subset types in Coq

Tags: random, coq

Yo!

I need a random stream of nats with guaranteed subset types, like `this stream will only give 0 < nat < 10`. Anyone up for helping me with this?

I found this function for generating random numbers:

```
CoFixpoint rand (seed n1 n2 : Z) : Stream Z :=
    let seed' := Zmod seed n2 in Cons seed' (rand (seed' * n1) n1 n2).
```

I want to replace `Z` with any subset type, e.g.

```
Definition Z_gt0 := { Z | Z > 0}.
```

So we have:

```
CoFixpoint rand (seed n1 n2 : Z_gt0) : Stream Z_gt0 :=
    let seed' := Zmod seed n2 in Cons seed' (rand (seed' * n1) n1 n2).
```

Now the problem is that `Zmod` does accept `Z` but not `Z_gt0`.

Do I have to redefine all functions? Or is there already a library function ready to use?

TO MOD: Please add a tag for subset-types or refinement-types.

Comment: Btw you should open the ``Z`` scope (globally or locally) for your definition of ``Z_gt0`` otherwise the ``_ < _`` test will be in ``nat``. Something like ``Definition Z_gt0 := { Z | Z > 0}%Z.`` should do the trick.

Comment: Right, so `Require Import ZArith`?

Comment: This is not enough, you will have to ``Open Scope Zscope`` (not sure about the syntax) at toplevel, or use the ``%Z`` local scope where necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your type is that `Zmod seed n2` is a positive integer that can be 0, so `seed'` can be 0, which means that `seed' * n1` can be 0 too.

In the end your `CoFixpoint` is not typable, the seed should be in some `Z_ge0` type, not in `Z_gt0`.

EDIT: to answer the part about the library, you might be interested by the `positive` type, which is the type of binary integer strictly greater than 0. In fact, `Z` is defined as:

```
Inductive Z : Set :=
    Z0 : Z (* 0 *)
  | Zpos : positive -> Z (* z > 0 *)
  | Zneg : positive -> Z (* z < 0 *)
```

However the problem is still the same: taking the modulo of positive integer can escape `positive` since you can end up with 0.

Comment: The thing is, I'd like to accept other subsets aswell, as `rand : Stream { Z | 10 < Z < 100}`. So I have to redefine `Zmod`, or? No, wait... `mod` can of course always be 0.

Comment: But if n1 and n2 are primes, `seed'` cannot be 0, right?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. What if the original seed is ``n1`` ?

Comment: Yeah, if `seed == n2` then there will be only zeroes in the stream. So `n1` and `n2` should be prime numbers, and `seed != n2`. The writer of this code sais that `you would have to choose n1 n2 to be primes, and you would obtain a fairly uniform distribution of numbers between 1 and n2-1`. If I can prove this, I could make this function return a subset type like `{z | z > 1 /\ z < n1}`, correct?

Comment: Sorry, mean `{z | z > 0 /\ z < n2}`.

Comment: seems ok. Having the original seed in ]O, n2[ seems to be enough to prove that all seeds will be too