# How to "extract" Z from subset type {z : Z | z > 0}

Tags: types, subset, coq

If a function take `Z` as arguments, it should also be possible to take any subset of `Z`, right? For example, `Zmod` takes two `Z` and return `Z`. Can I improve on this method with subset types without reimplementing it?

I want this:

```
Definition Z_gt0 := {z | z > 0}.

Definition mymod (n1 n2 : Z_gt0) :=
  Zmod n1 n2.
```

But Coq complains that `n1 is expected to have type Z`, of course. How can I make it work with `Z_gt0`? Coerce?

This question is related to my other one here: [Random nat stream and subset types in Coq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475258/random-nat-stream-and-subset-types-in-coq)

**Edit**: `proj1_sig` might do the trick, thanks Coq IRC channel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`proj1_sig` is the usual way to go. Another solution is to pattern match:

```
match z1 with
   exist _ z hz => ...
end
```

`z` will be your projection, and `hz` will be a proof that `z > 0`. I usually leave the first parameter anonymous since I know that `z : Z`.

I recent version of Coq, there is another way to do it, using `let` (because `sig` is an inductive with only one constructor):

```
Definition Zmod_gt0 (z1 z2: Z_gt0) : Z :=
  let (a, _) := z1 in
  let (b, _) := z2 in 
  Zmod a b.
```